# Copying and executing local files to a remote server with windows and linux using java

Tags: java, windows, linux, remote-access

What I'm attempting to do is copy a number of files from one host machine to a remote server using java and after the copy is made, I'll execute those files that I transferred.  The host machine may have some dependencies like requiring putty or some other program but I'm hoping that there might be a solution that doesn't require anything installed on the remote side.  And on top of that, this needs to be OS independent, though different methods can be used for different communications. I'll have access to the IP address and admin control (root username and password).

What I've had so far was that for Windows to Windows, I can mount the remote windows drive and access the files that way.  In Windows to Linux, I can use putty or a similar program to ssh into the remote box.  I'll also ssh from Linux to Linux and obviously I won't need putty.  I can't figure out what to do for a Linux to Windows instance that won't require me setting up some ssh method on the remote end.  Any ideas?  Any way (or library) to perform both the copy and/or execute methods that won't even be OS specific?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to use what Windows already offers: [rdesktop](http://www.rdesktop.org/) or the more comfortable [Terminal Server Client](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsclient) if you are on a Gnome machine.

To get the files to the Windows box, you can set up Samba Client on your Linux machine and mount the Windows file share, copy your files there, connect via rdesktop and then execute them.

Comment: Using samba requires some set up on the windows box.  Is there possibly another way that wouldn't require set up on that end?

Comment: No, I didn't mean Samba on the Windows boxes, just the Samba client on your Linux box, so that you are able to connect to Windows fileshares. You don't need to install anything Linux-specific for this solution.